# Ubuntu 10.04 is crashing and video output stops

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ubuntu-10.04

I recently got a new Ubuntu 10.04 desktop at work. However, the machine crashes every few hours, and the video output would stop. I suspect the issue is related to the drivers, so here is the "lspci -v" output:

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0100 (rev 09)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Capabilities:
>
> 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
>       I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
>       Memory behind bridge: e1500000-e15fffff
>       Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000dfffffff
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>       Kernel modules: shpchp
>
> 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 (rev 04)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
>       Memory at e16b0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
>       Capabilities:
>
> 00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point KT Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 02)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
>       I/O ports at 50a0 [size=8]
>       Memory at e1690000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: serial
>
> 00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 1502 (rev 04)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
>       Memory at e1600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
>       Memory at e1680000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
>       I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
>       Capabilities:
>
> 00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
>       Memory at e1670000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
>
> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
>       Memory at e1660000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
>       Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
>
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>       Kernel modules: shpchp
>
> 00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
>       I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
>       Memory behind bridge: e0a00000-e13fffff
>       Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000e09fffff
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>       Kernel modules: shpchp
>
> 00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4)
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
>       I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
>       Memory behind bridge: e1400000-e14fffff
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>       Kernel modules: shpchp
>
> 00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
>       Memory at e1650000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
>
> 00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4) (prog-if 01)
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
>       Capabilities:
>
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1c4e (rev 04)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt
>
> 00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 SATA RAID Controller (rev 04)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
>       I/O ports at 5090 [size=8]
>       I/O ports at 5080 [size=4]
>       I/O ports at 5070 [size=8]
>       I/O ports at 5060 [size=4]
>       I/O ports at 5020 [size=32]
>       Memory at e1640000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: ahci
>       Kernel modules: ahci
>
> 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 047e
>       Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
>       Memory at e1630000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
>       I/O ports at 5000 [size=32]
>       Kernel modules: i2c-i801
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV620 LE [Radeon HD 3450]
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0342
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
>       Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
>       Memory at e1520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
>       I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
>       Expansion ROM at e1500000 [disabled] [size=128K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: radeon
>       Kernel modules: radeon
>
> 04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
>       Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device a01f
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
>       Memory at e14c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
>       Memory at e1400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
>       I/O ports at 2000 [size=32]
>       Memory at e14e0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>       Expansion ROM at e1480000 [disabled] [size=256K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: e1000e
>       Kernel modules: e1000e

Anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data, you are using a sandy bridge based chipset.

Since ubuntu 10.04 came out in 2010, and sandy bridge came out in 2011, you are using an OS that is older than your hardware. Drivers will not even have anticipated what the technology is in sandy bridge.

Running older OS on newer hardware usually leads to problems (especially linux where the drivers are usually made by the community and not the manufacturers).

Try using a newer version of ubuntu

Comment: I updated to Ubuntu 12.02.1 LTS last week. No more crashes so far. :-)